# How to scrape images from urls scraped before (nested urls)

Tags: python, scrapy

I use Scrapy to scrape items of a website. There are bunch of informations including image urls. Can you help me figuring out how to extract images from these urls (`data["image_urls"]`).

I understand that I have to extend the media pipeline because Scrapy doesn't manage nested urls but I'm lost in the process.

```
import json
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from auctions_results.items import AuctionItem
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

from datetime import datetime

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
            "auctions_results", "json/input/scrape_demo_db.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['gm_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            data = AuctionItem()

            data["marque"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").extract_first().strip().split(" ", 2)[1]

            data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().split("-", 1)[0].strip()
            data["auction_country"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().rsplit(",", 1)[1].strip()
            data["auction_date"] = caritem.css("div.date::text").extract_first().replace(",", "").strip()

            data["image_urls"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a img::attr(src)").extract_first()
            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item
```

When I encode the results in JSON it looks like this:

```
[{
"gm_url": "url",
"results": [{
    "marque": "ferrari",
    "auction_house": "auction",
    "auction_country": "japan",
    "auction_date": "2019",
    "image_urls": "imgurl"
},
{
    "marque": "porsche",
    "auction_house": "auction2",
    "auction_country": "gb",
    "auction_date": "2018",
    "image_urls": "imgurl2"
}]
```

}, ....
]

I add the image item in items.py, activate the ITEM_PIPELINE and IMAGES_STORE in settings.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the get_media_requests method of the ImagesPipeline for this:

```
class DownloadImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for result in item['results']:
            image_url = result['image_urls']
            request = Request(url=image_url,
                              headers=headers)
            yield request
```

In your settings you should de-activate the ImagesPipeline and replace it with this 'DownloadImagesPipeline'.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a problem, I replace my ITEM_PIPELINES with `ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.DownloadImagesPipeline': 1}` and I get an error `NameError: Module 'scrapy.pipelines.images' doesn't define any object named 'DownloadImagesPipeline'`

Comment: Did you create a file images.py under a 'pipelines' folder in which you put the class DownloadImagesPipeline?

Comment: No I put it in the pipelines.py. But I don't understand exactly the logic of it.

Comment: Just make sure you have the right path, probably something like scrapy.pipelines.DownloadImagesPipeline in your case

Comment: I just have to insert the class in pipeline.py ? And add the path in settings (if I do that, I have the same problem) ?

Comment: Should work, yes. And you have to replace 'scrapy' with the name of your scrapy project

Comment: Perfect ! It works ! Now I have to think about a way to create a link to the picture directly in Scrapy but I'm going to ask it in another question. Thank you again !